# Bash Script: All files in directory

Tags: bash, recursion, concatenation

I'm a new coder and having trouble writing a bash script in which all the log files in my directory (number001.log, number002.log, ect.) get processed via a perl script (map_shifts2PDB.pl) and the results of each numberXXX.log file are concatenated to a results.out file. The perl script requires the following arguments `./map_shifts2PDB.pl <path of logfile> <path of test.pdb> (constant)` and the number of the log file to be processed. I don't know how to synchronize this to the log file being read in the loop. This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in ~/TrpCage_1L2Y/1L2Y_min_explicit/model1_charged/calculate/*.log; do

./map_shifts2PDB.pl ~/TrpCage_1L2Y/1L2Y_min_explicit/model1_charged/calculate ~/TrpCage_1L2Y/1L2Y
_min_explicit/model1_charged/test.pdb 1 >> results.out

done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just extract the number from the file name using parameter expansion:

```
num=${f##*/number}    # Delete everything up to /number.
num=${num%.log}       # Delete the extension.
./map_shifts2PDB.pl \ 
    ~/TrpCage_1L2Y/1L2Y_min_explicit/model1_charged/calculate \
    ~/TrpCage_1L2Y/1L2Y_min_explicit/model1_charged/test.pdb \
    $num >> results.out
```

What do you mean by "recursive" in the title?